# I have included submit button but the information send to another page without considering the submit button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

in my project http://pastebin.com/3LBRZBQe i have used a submit button which should work when i click it but without any click next page opens.....I have 30 entries in my database which i have to display on a web page in such a way that first of all first 10 entries should be displayed and after clicking next button another 10 entries should be displayed and so on.....but when i run the program last 10 entries are displayed...
i want to use requestDispatcher method  so that information should send to another jsp page....

Comment: It would be great if you can paste the content of the link in this question itself. Thanks

Comment: It seems you need pagination. And it seems natural that this code `<%getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DisplayResult1.jsp").forward(request,response);%>` will forward the request to the last page, since you have written this in all the JSPs except the last one. If you have 40 records will you have 4 JSPs, and if 50 then 5 JSPs? Also I wonder why have you used a JSP since you have used neither JSTL nor ELs but scriptlets. If you are new to JSP & Servlets then please follow some conceptual tutorials before you begin on such a complicated journey of spaghetti code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use add `parameters` to define the range of requested numbers of records
,and in next page get these `parameters`

like:

```
 /next?start=1&end=10
```

in next page :

```
request.getParameter("start");
request.getParameter("end");
```

and same for further...